# Jinja2: using a pandas dataframe or string variable

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm getting unexpected output from my jinja2 template.

I have an instance where a table is either populated with a single value, or a set of values. The presentation for each is a little different, so I thought I could just check the state of the template variable with a conditional `{% if my_variable is mapping %}`, and proceed accordingly with my template code.
Here's my template code:

```
<table class="summary_table halfpage">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>
                     My Table
                 </th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           {% if my_variable is mapping %}
               {% for key,value in my_variable.iterrows() %}
                   <tr>
                     <td>
                       <p><strong>{{ value['Column1'] }} : </strong> {{ value['Column2'] }}</p>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <p><strong>{{ my_variable }}</strong></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            {% endif %}
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

This works fine when my_variable is a string (ie. not a mapping). But when it is a mapping, instead of getting a nicely rendered table I get this:

```
           <table class="summary_table halfpage">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>
                     My Table
                 </th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <p><strong>    Column1    Column2
0     6th  name 1
1     7th  name2
2     8th  name 2
3     9th  name 4</strong></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

           </tbody>
       </table>
```

Here's the python code that produces that template variable, and loads it into the template:

```
def load_data(data_name, grade=None):
    file_path = os.path.join(data_path, for_who + "_" + when + "_" + data_name + ".csv")
    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_path = False   
    if file_path:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    else:
        data = False
    return data

def make_my_variable():
    data = load_data("relevant_data") 
    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        data = load_data("other_relevent_data")
        #in the case of "other_relevent_data" the column names are different
        data = data["ColumnA"].iloc[0]
    return data

report = report_tmpl.render(
    my_variable = make_my_variable()
)

html_output = os.path.join(output_path, for_who + "_" + date_transform(when) + ".html")
with open(html_output, 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(report)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This renders just fine without he conditional in there.

*EDIT:* Added python code that creates my_variable and renders the template

Comment: Please post the code you use to produce this output. The template is not enough apparantly.

Comment: Thanks, and done. good idea :)

Comment: Apparantly that `pandas.DataFrame` is not detected to be a mapping. Have you tried to just feed the relevant data to the renderer? e.g., `my_variable = [(v["Col1"], v["Col2"]) for k,v in df.iterrows()]`

Comment: Hi @moooeeeep, so essentially, I'd be transforming my dataframe to a map. Is that the idea?

Comment: Or a list. A dictionary would be more like `{k: v for k,v in df.iterrows()}`. But that'd be the basic idea.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. I had to change my code a bit too. I'll post an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @moooeeeep I was able to solve this. As he mentions, the problem comes from the fact that pd.DataFrame is not recognized as a mapping in jinja2. So, instead I transformed my data frame into a list:

```
def make_my_variable():
    data = load_data("relevant_data") 
    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        data = load_data("other_relevent_data")
        #in the case of "other_relevent_data" the column names are different
        data = data["ColumnA"].iloc[0]
    else:
        data = [(v["Column1"], v["Column2"]) for k,v in data .iterrows()]
    return data
```

and on the template side I changed the conditional **from:**

```
{% if my_variable is mapping %}
    {% for key,value in my_variable.iterrows() %}
#and latter...
<p><strong>{{ value['Column1'] }} grade:</strong> {{ value['Column2'] }}</p>
```

**to:**

```
{% if most_popular_games is iterable and my_variable is not string %}
    {% for value in my_variable %}
#and..
<p><strong>{{ value[0] }} grade:</strong> {{ value[1] }}</p>
```

Altogether, the final template code looks like this now:

```
<table class="summary_table halfpage">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>
                     My Table
                 </th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           {% if my_variable is iterable and my_variable is not string %}
               {% for value in my_variable %}
                   <tr>
                     <td>
                       <p><strong>{{ value[0] }} : </strong> {{ value[1] }}</p>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <p><strong>{{ my_variable }}</strong></p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            {% endif %}
           </tbody>
       </table>
```